# Get Coinbase.com miner fee before sending to another address

Tags: transaction-fees, client, coinbase.com, php

I am using coinbase.com php library to send bitcoin to another address. But every-time i am sending bitcoin the fee is shown to me after sending the bitcoin. This is causing me some problem. Is there anyway to get the miner fee for a transaction before I send the amount. Thank you.

**I am using the official PHP library of coinbase.com

Comment: Coinbase is notoriously inefficient with their transactions (no batching, no SegWit) and still overcharging on fees. Then they blame Bitcoin. If you depend on Coinbase your service _will_ fail once the fee market picks up again. Also: not your keys, not your bitcoins. Do not keep bitcoin on an exchange. See MtGox and many other examples in history.

Comment: All perfectly valid points but not answering the question Jannes....